# Randomly getting logged out

Tags: xubuntu, session

It just started today. I'm getting repeatedly logged out of Xubuntu. I have also had a new option come up after logging in that lets me load a session. I've just been loading default and I'd like to know how I can get rid of this screen as well as find out why I'm being logged out. I'm also noticing an error message everytime I get to the desktop that says "Invalid option: -session".

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem a couple of weeks ago. The "invalid option" window was created by spotify on my computer.

I just deleted my `~/.cache/sessions` folder, which fixed it for me. (Actually I made a backup just in case). I've not noticed any adverse effects.

You can read more about sessions [here](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-session/start).